# Is it possible to convert Unicode ASCII bytes[ ] to actual strings(Hi)

Tags: c#, encoding, serial-port

Is it possible to convert following bytes[] to a string as "Hi". Currently it is showing as "H�"

```
//"Hi" - is actual message
byte[] bytes = {72,175};
string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(data); //H�
```

Comment: `175` is a [`Macron` character `¯`](https://unicode-table.com/en/00AF/) but you want `105` which is `i` see https://dotnetfiddle.net/x1q3bw

Comment: Why do you think `i` is `175` and not `105`?

Comment: Checking the easy reverse `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hi");` would have told you.

Comment: UTF-8 is one encoding of Unicode. But if you have UTF-8 bytes > 127, they are multibytes, so you miss a byte. Or it is not UTF-8

Comment: Seeing now the serial port tag. Do you now what encoding your hardware on that port sends? Maybe you are just using the wrong encoding. And i don't now any encoding/codepage that would be fitting.

Comment: I am sending "Hi" message using serial port communication with help of SerialPort class. At the sender side, I have used Encoding.ASCII and also tried UTF8 but for all type of encoding I getting some different char/symbol except start char only.

Comment: @GuruStron, As per my expectation it should be 105 but it changed as 175. I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: Are you sure your serial parameters are the same on both ends? If you have different parameters for data bits, or start or stop bits, you can read improper data.

Comment: Note that your title makes no sense: you can have a collection of bytes, which represents either a unicode character or string (differing based on encoding used) or an ASCII string (which is a specific single encoding). You can't have a unicode ASCII bytes collection.